# Merge multiple objects with different format in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json

I create below objects,

```
products = [
    {id:1, name: a},
    {id:2, name: b},
]

prices = [
    {id:1, month:1, price:1},
    {id:1, month:2, price:1},
    {id:2, month:1, price:1},
    {id:2, month:2, price:1},
]
```

so i want output as product prices,

```
product_prices = [
    {id:1, name: a, prices: [{id:1, month:1, price:1},{id:1, month:2, price:1}]}, 
    {id:2, name: b, prices: [{id:2, month:1, price:1},{id:2, month:2, price:1}]},
]
```

Below is my code i try

```
let subscriptionProductWithPrices = []


    subscriptionProducts.forEach(x => {
      subscriptionProductMonthPrices.forEach(y => {
        if (x.sub_product_id === y.sub_product_id) {
          subscriptionProductWithPrices = [
            {
              id: x.sub_product_id,
              name: x.sub_product_name,
              unit_id: x.facility_units_name,
              price: x.total_price,
              quantity: x.sub_product_quantity,
              recurring: x.sub_product_recurring,
              in_agreement: x.sub_product_in_agreement,
              start_date: x.sub_product_start_date,
              end_date: x.sub_product_end_date,
              prices:
                subscriptionProductMonthPrices


            }
          ]
          return subscriptionProductWithPrices
        }
      })
    })
```

this code  only return last product id with all prices but i want output as below,

```
    product prices [{id:1, name: a, prices[{{id:1, month:1, price:1},{id:1, month:2, price:1}]}, {id:2, name: b, prices[{{id:2, month:1, price:1},{id:2, month:2, price:1}]}]
```

can someone help me?

Comment: replace "subscriptionProductWithPrices = [" with subscriptionProductWithPrices.push( as you are wanting to add to the array when there is a match, not set it to the current match only. This is why it only has the last result from what I can see. There may be some other issues, but let's work on them after you get all your results in the subscriptionProductWithPrices array.

Comment: @Spangle using above my code currently i get this result  

product prices [{id:2, name: b, prices[{id:1, month:1, price:1},{id:1, month:2, price:1}, {id:2, month:1, price:1},{id:2, month:2, price:1}]}]. It return last product with all the prices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Nithin Your code is fine but it is trying to push the **filtered price array** into **product.prices** array which will result array into an array instead of an array of object. So a simple modification will do the magic.

Here is an Optimized code of it.

```
let products = [{id:1, name: 'a'}, {id:2, name: 'b'}];
let prices = [{id:1, month:1, price:1},{id:1, month:2, price:1}, {id:2, month:1, price:1}, {id:2, month:2, price:1}];
products.map(prod=>{
// filter returns an array which can be directly assigned to prices
  prod.prices=prices.filter(pric=>pric.id===prod.id);
});
//Print the result stored in products with its corresponding prices
console.log(products);
```

Answer (score 2):

Merge the products and prices based on the id field as below -

```
let products = [{id:1, name: 'a'}, {id:2, name: 'b'}];
let prices = [{id:1, month:1, price:1},{id:1, month:2, price:1}, {id:2, month:1, price:1}, {id:2, month:2, price:1}];

// loop through the products list
let newProductsWithPrices=products.map(product=> {
  product.prices=[];     // for each product create an empty prices array field
  product.prices.push(prices.filter(price=>price.id===product.id)) // add the matching prices into the prices field
  return product;
});

console.log(newProductsWithPrices);
// "[{"id":1,"name":"a","prices":[[{"id":1,"month":1,"price":1},{"id":1,"month":2,"price":1}]]},{"id":2,"name":"b","prices":[[{"id":2,"month":1,"price":1},{"id":2,"month":2,"price":1}]]}]"
```